# Search contents of files within specified directory

Tags: spotlight

I aim to search the contents of files at a specified directory.

take an example in spotlight search

```
'Marked important question' in dir('/desktop)
```

How can such a task be accomplished?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search in a particular folder and subfolder through Spotlight](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113191/search-in-a-particular-folder-and-subfolder-through-spotlight)

Comment: a good answer there.Is it possible just to use 'command' instead of 'GUI'? @Scot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From the Finder**

An easy way is to open a Finder Window to the folder of interest, and use the search box in the upper right corner. For this to work effectively, Finder Preferences should be adjusted as follows:

Under `Finder/Preferences/Advanced` tab, change

When performing a search: to

`"Search the Current Folder"`

**From the Command Line**

Use mdfind, with the -onlyin option, as below, which will search the current directory for all files with a .jpg suffix:

`mdfind -name .jpg -onlyin .`

Comment: Is it possible to use `command` in spotlight?

Comment: @JoseTronco Do you mean from the command line - yes, you can use the `-onlyin` option.

Comment: from search bar after press `command` + 'space'.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible with Apple's built-in Spotlight GUI (there is a specifier entitled `kMDItemPath`. But, it doesn't appear to work as you desire: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70939/how-to-locate-a-file-in-spotlight-using-folder-and-file-name